# Kotlin: How to simplify this filter firstNorNull call chain?

Tags: android, kotlin

I got a warning from Android Studio: Call chain on collection type may be simplified.

```
val hit = hits.filter {
        val trackable = it.trackable
        trackable is Plane && trackable.isPoseInPolygon(it.hitPose)
    }.firstOrNull() ?: return
```

Comment: Just click the highlighted expression and press `Alt+Enter` to see the simplification.

Comment: `list.filter { condition }.firstOrNull()` ==> `list.firstOrNull { condition }`

Comment: @zapl they want to return if it's null, so the first is exactly what they're doing.

Comment: A good way to approach this problem is to write a few unit tests, make them green, and then tinker with your code until you're satisfied with it and your tests are still green!

Comment: @TheWanderer it doesn't work on Mac

Comment: @Egor Smart, thanks

Comment: Use `Cmd`+`Enter`

Answer (score 3):

```
list.firstOrNull { condition }
```